# Rules Specificity

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

```css
body {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.brown {
  color: brown;
  font-weight: 200;
}
.large {
   font-size: 28px;
}
.normal {
   font-size: 18px;
   color: blue;
   font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>CSS Specificity</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>

    <p class='normal'>Normal and blue text!</p>
    <p class='normal large brown'>Large and brown text!</p>

  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The output should be "Normal and blue text!" in blue and "Large and brown text" in large [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyYCk.png)brown
I have tried so many combination and still ca't get it right - please help and thanks.

Comment: I do appreciate the help here. Just trying  to learn how to code and following some instruction. I finished HTM basics and now trying to finish CCS basics. later moving forward to JavaScript. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The rule for `normal` is last in the CSS, so it overwrites the color in `brown` if both classes are applied